# What is the problem on this jquery form that checks for number of chars in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is a code that enables the submit button if there are more than 100 chars in the textarea. However I can't get it work. Maybe the jquery version is wrong? I don't know.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea id="textareaId"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submitId" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function () {
    if(("#textareaId").val().length > 100) {
      $("#submitId").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      $("#submitId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  }, 500); //Runs every 0.5s
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are missing the `$` by `("#textareaId")`

and try using an `onchange` instead of a `setInterval`  this might be more efficient:

```
$("#textareaId").change(function () {
   if((this.value).length > 100) {
     $("#submitId").removeAttr("disabled");
   } else {
     $("#submitId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   }
}).keyup(function(){$(this).change()});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/7Kch9/

Comment: Nice, but If you don't click outside the textarea then you will not get the submit button enabled...

Comment: Great thanks for the update. Another small tweak. This form will be used basically as a right click paste content. If you refresh the page and just paste it will not work properly. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a `$` in front of `("#textareaId")`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to check after every 0.5 seconds? You could have simply checked on change of the textinput.

```
$('#textareaID').change(function () {
   //you logic for checking 100 characters here.
});
```

Comment: @Neal hehe.. came to know "not just that you are good at answering.. but your typing speed also matters in SO" :D

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach binding on 'keyup' rather than 'change'. It's also best to disable the button with JS rather than in the HTML.

http://jsbin.com/aviji4

Answer (score 0):

I've done it slightly different than the rest, same principle though:

```
var $submit = $("#submitId"),
    $textarea = $("#textareaId"),
    NUM_OF_CHARS_TO_ENABLE_SUBMIT = 100;

$textarea.keyup(function() {

    if (this.value.length > NUM_OF_CHARS_TO_ENABLE_SUBMIT) {

        $submit.removeAttr("disabled");

    } else { $submit.attr("disabled", "disabled"); }

});
```

View the ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/4V3ws/)***.

Comment: @Neal - I don't need to copy you, buddy.  I don't believe I see another solution that looks identical to mine.  And I did state that it was the same principle, e.g. using keyup(), as well as, slightly different.  Some people like nice looking code.

Comment: @Neal - Not to mention, you are binding to change() and keyup() which isn't really needed.  Mine uses a constant for easy update, caching, and works on typing text, as well as, right-click paste.  I believe it's a production ready, well-optimized piece of code.